# How do I use functions and get the results from the function?

Tags: r

I have the following code in R which creates a vector of names (Team 1, Team 2 etc...).

```
  creatingTeam <- function() {

  names = c()

for (i in 1:10){
var = i
x <- paste0("team", var, sep=" ")
names <- append(names, x)
}
  print(names)

  }
```

It all works fine but when I want to use it in my R console I get this:

```
 > names
 function (x)  .Primitive("names")
```

Could anybody tell me how I could write a function so I can access the variables?

Comment: All you're doing there is `c(paste("team", 1:10), c())` which is the same as `paste("team", 1:10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is an example problem and not what you actually want to do (if it is see Mamoun's answer). You've mixed up the function and repeating steps. Your function should be an individual case and then you can loop the function.

Here's a tidy up:

Create function

```
creatingTeam <- function(i) {
    paste("team", i)
}
```

R is a vectorised language, so you often don't need to specifically express loops. Here are a couple of ways you could repeat your function

```
team.names <- creatingTeam(1:10)
team.names <- sapply(1:10, creatingTeam)
```

Your team.names vector now has 10 character elements (team 1, team 2, ...), you can access these as a whole by `team.names` or inidividual elements by `team.names[5]` (for the fifth element).

You could also repeat your function with a for loop, but as you've tried it's a few more lines of code to get it to write to a vector.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the function in R, assign it to a new variable, like this:

```
> newVariable <- creatingTeam()
```

Now the next time you call `newVariable` it will display your "team" AS LONG AS the very last line in your function is `names`, R functions return whatever the last line of the function is.

Now when you call `newVariable` it will display the contents of `names`, giving you access to your team as a character vector.